# Delete from selected table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to delete a record from selected table in ASP.NET MVC.

So this is my action:

```
public JsonResult DeleteFromTable()
{
    int IDtoDelete = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["itemId"]);
    string MyTableName = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["TblName"]);
    bool results = false;

    try
    {
        using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
        {
            Type tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);

            switch (MyTableName)
            {
                case "CourseTbl":
                    break;

                case "CourseDescTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
                    break;

                case "CourseSubDesc":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseSubDesc);
                    break;

                case "InternTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(InternShip);
                    break;

                case "ContactTbl":
                    Contact cn = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ID == IDtoDelete);   //This line here is throwing error
                    bool bcn = UtilityMethods<Contact, int>.InsertEntity(db, cn);
                    break;
            }

            return new JsonResult { Data = "results", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
        return new JsonResult { Data = "Not Found", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

and I've created a class where I'm passing these parameters and calling my functions:

```
internal class UtilityMethods<TEntity, Tid> where TEntity : class
{
     public static bool DeleteEntity(EBContext dbContext, TEntity entity)
     {
         try
         {
             dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
             dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);

             dbContext.SaveChanges();

             return true;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             string abc = ex.Message;
             return false;
         }
    }  
}
```

But I'm getting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert Type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'EBazar.Models.Contact'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missimg a cast?)

Comment: Return type of LINQ method `Where` is IQueryable and you are trying to assign it to a single object of Contact class. That's why you are seeing this error. You should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`

Comment: So how can I select the record from the IDtoDelete. In order to pass it to my function?

Comment: `Contact cn = db.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == IDtoDelete);` (to return a single object)

Comment: And not related, but change your signature to `public JsonResult DeleteFromTable(string TblName, int itemId)` and let the `DefaultModelbinder` do its magic.

Comment: Contact cn = db.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == IDtoDelete); that solved my problem .

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the `Where` part into `FirstOrDefault` in order to take the first object with that condition if it exsist.

- `FirstOrDefault` returns the default value of a type if no item matches the predicate. For reference types that is null.

So you just have to check for null first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Contact cn = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ID == IDtoDelete);
```

write

```
Contact cn = db.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == IDtoDelete);
```